# How do I correct this sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why do I get the TraceBack

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
between parent/child tables on relationship County.Legislators - 
there are no foreign keys linking these tables.

Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a
ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

with the following models:

```
class County(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tblCounty'
    CountyCode = Column('CountyCode', String, primary_key=True)
    Legislators = relationship('Legislators', backref='County', lazy='dynamic')

class Legislators(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'VLegislators'
    EmployeeNo = Column('EmployeeNo', String, primary_key=True)
    CountyCode = Column('CountyCode', String, ForeignKey('County.CountyCode'))
```

I'm trying to map a public facing MS SQL database provided by the State of New Hampshire.  So no schema changes allowed.

Why does it complain about the lack of a ForeignKey relation when one is clearly defined in class Legislators?

Comment: the error is entirely about setting up the ORM; at this stage (or really any stage) SQLA neither knows nor cares what FK are physically in the db

Comment: note that since you're explicitly providing the column names anyway, you could use attribute names like `country_code` that read more naturally as attributes in Python

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK you should use tablename in ForeignKey:

```
CountyCode = Column('CountyCode', String, ForeignKey('tblCounty.CountyCode'))
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thank you.

Comment: or, for reduced confusion, don't use a string when you can avoid it: `ForeignKey(County.CountyCode)`

Comment: Turns out this also solves most of the Errors - thanks a lot for this tip !!!